# jQuery Mobile UI problems on 2nd level pages

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a project that is five pages: 1 landing and 4 second level pages. I'm using page transitions, panels, and popups. The issue I have is that things like popups and panels work on the landing page but when I navigate to the second level pages, popups and panels don't work. I don't have any errors in console. If I navigate directly to the second level pages, they work. It seems as though navigating to the subpages does not activate some of the JS or code necessary.

Unfortunately, it's on a closed network for a client so I can't upload an example. Any ideas or has anyone run into this? I know that jQuery will only fire JS that's within the `data-role="page"` tags.

Thanks.

Comment: Each page should have its' own panel and popups. If you're using jQM 1.4, you can use external panel and popups.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that each page does have it's own panel and popups that are not external, just local divs.

Comment: Make sure they have different IDs'.

Comment: Winner, winner, chicken dinner! Thanks for the help, I was pulling my hair out. Shame I can't use the same divs but I understand that it's loading all of them at the same time.

Comment: If you use jQM 1.4, you can use _external_ panels and popups that can be accessed from any page. _External_ means, they aren't wrapped in `data-role=page`, they belong to `$.mobile.pageContainer` = `<body>` by default.